# How to map a model property to a foreign table relationship

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Please forgive the title as I'm not sure of the wording needed to describe the problem properly.

I have a customer table, an email address table, an email address type table, and the matching models.

> **Customer Table**
> CustomerId, Firstname, Lastname
>
> **EmailAddress Table**
> EmailAddressId, EmailAddress, EmailAddressType, CustomerId
>
> **EmailAddressType Table**
> EmailAddressTypeId, Description

I would like to add properties "Primary Email", "Secondary Email", "Tertiary Email" addresses to my Customer model but having an issue in figuring out how to code it properly.

I do realize what I want to do doesn't fit the relationship type of the tables in the DB. This is the business requirement for an interim solution until we can re-code all of this logic.

Comment: You'll need to add Navigation Properties to Customer, look up Navigation properties and FK

Comment: @TMcKeown Thanks for the quick reply. Since it's a 1 to many relationship how would I code this so the PrimaryEmail field will map to the correct row in the EmaillAddress table with the correct EmaillAddressTypeId?

Comment: As an idea, maybe I can use a normal navigation property for the 1 to many then some NotMapped properties where the get() methods will have the .Where() clause etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a native solution for what I was looking to do.

So I ended up adding them as non-mapped settings that simply use linq to retrieve from the one-to-many that I added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:  EmailAddressType Table is skipped, and i assume the secondary and tertiary email address are optional, the primary email is  a required field.
The relationship between Customer table and EmailAddress table is configured in the OnModelCreating method.

```
       public class Customer
        {
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public virtual EmailAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
            public virtual EmailAddress SecondaryAddress { get; set; }
            public virtual EmailAddress TeritaryAddress { get; set; }
        }

        public class EmailAddress
        {
            public int EmailAddressId { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }

        public class ShoppingDb : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
            public DbSet<EmailAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                var customerEntity= modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();
                customerEntity.HasKey(c => c.CustomerId);
                customerEntity.Property(c => c.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50);
                customerEntity.Property(c => c.LastName).HasMaxLength(50);
                customerEntity.HasRequired(c =>  
 c.PrimaryAddress).WithRequiredDependent();                 
                customerEntity.HasOptional(c => c.SecondaryAddress).WithOptionalDependent();
                customerEntity.HasOptional(c => c.TeritaryAddress).WithOptionalDependent();

                var addressEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<EmailAddress>();
                addressEntity.HasKey(c => c.EmailAddressId);
                addressEntity.Property(c => c.Address).HasMaxLength(200);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would I tell which row in the EmailAddress table is the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd address? Also, I have to use the EmailAddressType table for this solution.

Comment: check the table scheme built in the sql server management studio, you'll find three foreign keys in the Customer table. You don't have to tell the three addresses, because the Customer entity class has references to each EmailAddress. The implementation of EmailAddressType table is similar , just configure the foreign key between EmailAddressType table and EmailAddress table.

Comment: One of the requirements was to avoid adding columns to the Customer table. This is why I'm trying to create a temp. workaround.